# Component claiming state prop is undefined eventhough it is, Auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, state, react-redux

Im trying to log out a user as well as displaying a register/login div or profile section, depending if a user is logged in or not, Im trying to do this on a component that gets render on my main app.

Using ReduxDevTools I can see that the auth state changes when I log in a user or not, but when I try to render the LeftContainer setting auth: state.auth I get auth is undefined,

error:

Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `auth` is marked as required in `LeftContainer`, but its value is `undefined`.

---

LeftContainerProfile/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../../containers/SignIn/authActions';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Logo from '../Logo/Logo';
import SocialLinks from '../SocialLinks/social_links';
import ProfileContainer from './profile';
import LinksContainer from './about_links';


const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 4%;
  // height:  100vh;

`;

const Button = styled(Link)`
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
`;

class LeftContainer extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout();
  }


  render() {

    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

    const userLinks = (
      <div>
        <ProfileContainer />
        <Button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}> LOGOUT </Button>
      </div>
    );

    const guestLinks = (
       <div>
            <Button to='/login'>LOGIN</Button>
            <Button to='/sign-up'>REGISTER</Button>
       </div> 
    );

    return (

          <Wrapper>

            { isAuthenticated ? userLinks : guestLinks }

             <LinksContainer />
             <SocialLinks />
          </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

LeftContainer.propTypes = {
  auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(LeftContainer);
```

---

Im trying to get the state of auth but i get either undefined or object

here is a picture from reduxdevtools
https://gyazo.com/b189a75e1123cb198412adf93bdd3497

---

edit 3: When I do this

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth 
  };
}
```

I get this
https://gyazo.com/432247229816e4a68a50133834b551c9

maybe this will help people in helping find the solution to my problem

---

edit 4: I found a solution but Im not sure if this was the correct way of going about this, can someone maybe explain why state.auth was not giving my desire result, is it something in my reducer or something else? here is my solution

```
class LeftContainer extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout();
  }



  render() {

    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;

    const userLinks = (
      <div>
        <ProfileContainer />
        <Button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}> LOGOUT </Button>
      </div>
    );

    const guestLinks = (
       <div>
            <Button to='/login'>LOGIN</Button>
            <Button to='/sign-up'>REGISTER</Button>
       </div> 
    );

    return (

          <Wrapper>
            { isAuthenticated ? userLinks : guestLinks }
               <div>
            {/*<Button to='/login'>LOGIN</Button>
            <Button to='/sign-up'>REGISTER</Button>*/}
       </div> 
             <LinksContainer />
             <SocialLinks />
          </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

// LeftContainer.propTypes = {
//   auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
//   logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
// }

    // LeftContainer.propTypes = {
    //   isAuthenticated: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    //   logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    // }
    // LeftContainer.defaultProps = {
    //     isAuthenticated: true,
    // }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      console.log(state._root.entries[3][1].isAuthenticated);
      return {
        isAuthenticated: state._root.entries[3][1].isAuthenticated
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(LeftContainer);
```

Comment: Maybe the first time when the component renders the `auth` prop is given no value. And only on the 2nd render the prop will be populated. Try checking in your render function if the prop has a value and only then use it in your render logic.

Comment: how would I do that im still fairly new to react.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Component Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), and in particular the [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) method and log your props.

Answer (score 1):

or a much simpler approach (than the one I've listed in the comment):

I treated the `isAuthenticated` directly from the `mapeStateToProps` function and made it a `bool` value for more readiblity. This is less error prone because you don't pass a nested object on props. Also as a fallback I've added a defaultProp value.

Hope this does the trick.

```
class LeftContainer extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
      logout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logout();
      }


      render() {

        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;

        const userLinks = (
          <div>
            <ProfileContainer />
            <Button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}> LOGOUT </Button>
          </div>
        );

        const guestLinks = (
           <div>
                <Button to='/login'>LOGIN</Button>
                <Button to='/sign-up'>REGISTER</Button>
           </div> 
        );

        return (

              <Wrapper>

                { isAuthenticated ? userLinks : guestLinks }

                 <LinksContainer />
                 <SocialLinks />
              </Wrapper>
        );
      }
    }

    LeftContainer.propTypes = {
      isAuthenticated: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    LeftContainer.defaultProps = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth && state.auth.isAuthenticated
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(LeftContainer);
```